# Twig remove breaklines

Tags: twig

So I've got the following code:

```
{{ use('frontend/assets/AppAsset')}}
{{ register_app_asset() }}
{{ this.beginPage() }}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{app.language}}">
<head>
```

But on the compiled html file I see 3 empty lines before `<!doctype html>`. How Can I fix this? Using `{% spaceless %} {% endspaceless %}` produces 2 empty lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can trim whitespace by adding *whitespace control modifier* (hyphen) in your tags – see [Whitespace Control section in documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#whitespace-control).

E.g.:

```
{{- use('frontend/assets/AppAsset')}}
{{ register_app_asset() }}
{{ this.beginPage() -}}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{app.language}}">
<head>
```